# Increment all numbers

Tags: excel, math, editor, notepad++

Suppose I have a list of numbers starting with 32,33,33.1,34 and so on. So what i am trying to achieve is , if I will replace the number 32 to 42 then all other numbers should also change like 42,43,43.1,44. Is there any way to achieve this using any editor or logic or may be in excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In an excel sheet, you can use Paste Special to change all the values in one go:

1. Type `10` in a cell somewhere, and copy that cell.
2. Select the range containing the numbers and "Paste Special" > "Add".

Answer (score 0):

In Excel. Put the number 32 in cell A1. Then in A2, put '=A1+1'. In A2 put '=A1+1.1' etc. Then when you change 32 to 42, all the other cells will be updated automatically.

Comment: But I will do this then i will change every value of A1 which doe not make sense.If in a single column i have value like 32,33,33.1,33.2,34 and so on , Can I replace all those by replacing 32 to 42 by changing one value only.